# Effecient way of moving multiple vehicles in a simulation

Tags: java, multithreading, animation, concurrency, threadpool

So, I'm in doubt to which way is the most optimal in the situation given below:

I have a simulation of vehicles moving along roads on a map. Moving them is no problem and they obey traffic lights etc. However my question is, what's the most efficient way of moving the vehicles. Right now I have a thread per road so one thread moves vehicles along the road going south to north, another one for the road going from west to east etc. But it's not very optimal and very slow. Also, I'm finding it hard to allow the thread to keep track of the distances between the cars so they can slow down and not run past each other.

Do I need to have a thread pool using the `Executor` class in the `java.util.concurrent` package and then have one thread per vehicle and then free the thread once the vehicle leaves the simulation? Or will this too make it slow?

So in conclusion if I did not make it clear above, I'm attempting to find an optimal way of keeping track of vehicles currently in the simulation(map). I have tried to have one thread per road letting vehicles through but it's not a good solution as I eventually need the vehicles to have their own sort of logic.

Comment: Which actions can affect the driving of the vehicles? Only the crossings, or also how crowded the streets are? Maybe you can use event-driven simulation using a queue of Events to simulate instead of really moving the cars.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_event_simulation

Comment: how do you do actual animation / drawing? I suspect this might be issue slowing things down... your simulation resembles a game loop, and these normally run in one thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have one thread for the whole simulation.  The locking overhead (CPU and coding overhead) is likely to be greater than the benefit of having multiple threads.

> I eventually need the vehicles to have their own sort of logic.

I would have a method to call on each object like `move()` and is called for all objects repeatedly in the one thread.  Each car or object knows how it should move.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to know what your simulation actually does, like how do the cars decide where they go and how fast, when they stop, etc. Anyway, this seems to be a big model comprised of many cars, roads, traffic light, etc. And for multithreading, it must be well protected (locked or synchronized). Could you split the work in jobs based on time-steps and then look at each car in parallel? Seems better to think in small tasks than in threads, so you can choose the number of threads later.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an Actor Model like [Akka](http://akka.io/) for your simulation? Actor Models are used for Continuous Simulations (as opposed to Discrete Event Simulation).